# ASP.NET C# gridview Store the checkbox value in access from Grid View

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i've a gridview and form. I've searched over Internet but can not find how to store the multiple checkbox selection in the data base(MS Access)...actually i want to store ID of the skill in junction table to make many to many relationship..
Can you help me in this... Thanks

```
<Columns>
     <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
     <asp:BoundField DataField="Skills" HeaderText="Skills" SortExpression="Skills" />
     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
           <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" runat="server"  />
            </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

Comment: A suggestion, store id's of checboxes in db as string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imho, the best approach is to try to get the data into the form the control expects.  I'm not much of an access guy - can Access have views and stored procedures?

I'm going to do this in a database-oriented approach since that's how I feel today, but there's C#-based approaches that will be very similar to this.

I'll answer this part for general SQL, but you may need somebody more domain-specific to figure out how to do it in Access.  Let's imagine you have two tables: SkillType and PersonHasSkill.   SkillType would be the big global list of skills (Coding, Writing, Zombie-slaying) and PersonHasSkill would be the relationship between your people and your skills (Fred has Coding and Zombie-Slaying).

Create a View against your SkillType cross-joined against Person.  This creates a view that shows every possible combination of person and skill-type.  Then we take an with an outer-join against the PersonHasSkill that actually defines whether this particular combination of skill and person actually exists - in this case the PersonHasSkill columns will be null in our view.  So then we check for that Null value and use that for a column in our view that tells us whether this PersonHasSkill thing is true or not.

In most SQL languages, this would be something like

```
CREATE VIEW SkillView
SELECT Person.PersonID
, SkillType.*
, CASE WHEN PersonHasSkill.SomeColumn IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS HasSkill
FROM SkillType
CROSS JOIN Person
LEFT OUTER JOIN PersonHasSkill 
  ON SkillType.SkillTypeID = PersonHasSkill.SkillTypeID     
  AND PersonHasSkill.PersonID = Person.PersonID
```

Use that for your AccessDataSource's select target.  If you like, you could use a proc instead of a view.  Or skip the View and just stuff that right into the select body of your AccessDataSource without the "CREATE VIEW" part and with a "WHERE" clause.  Whichever.

Use the <%# Eval %> syntax to do the actual binding.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178366.ASPX

You can't actually use the pre-baked update logic provided by the GridView for this because those are designed for doing one row at a time instead of a whole table full of crap.  So we'll skip the #Bind two-way approach and just #Eval one-way.

In short, the field on the control that you wish to bind to a data value, you set the control field equal to '<%# Eval("HasSkill)" #>' - use single-quotes because you have to use double-quotes within the bind expression.

So for your case?

```
        <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" runat="server" Checked='<# Eval("HasSkill") />
        </ItemTemplate>
```

And now we have the data in the table.

For update?  Sucks to be you, we have to do it all in code-behind.  You can access the state of your checkboxes to do your update... which your update isn't really an update.  If the checkbox is "false" you're going to DELETE from your UserHasSkill table, and if the checkbox is TRUE you're going to insert... and you have to check if the row already exists in the UserHasSkill table so the thing doesn't bomb out.  To get the state of your checkboxes, do

```
ForEach(GridViewRow row in MyGridView.Rows)
{
  if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) //avoid header/footer rows.
  {
    var myCheckBox = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkSelect");
    //myCheckBox.Checked tells you if it's checked or not, yay!
    var myPrimaryKey = (GuidOrIntOrSomething)MyGridView.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value;
    //now you have your Key and the checkbox for whether the user has checked it 
    //and you can do your update/insert/delete/whatever against the DB.
  }
}
```

If you want to avoid reading each field from the database before deciding whether or not to delete/insert, you can save the results of your old fetch into ViewState so you'll have them later.  It's a small list so that won't break ViewState.

So yeah, real simple.